# Can I use PowerShell script with Functions in Azure Devops "Powershell@2" task?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a powershell script that includes functions defined in it. When I run it manually the script works fine and reference to the functions works fine.

But when I when I run it inside Azure Devops pipeline "Powershell@2" task, the script gets stuck at the point where first function is referenced and just hangs.

Is there a particular way I need to call functions in this script?

Comment: Please, add a small example of your script.

Comment: Hi there, what is the behavior when you run this script on your local machine? Does it require any interactive input? Please share a minimal reproducible code/script to help understand your scenario.